# Wine yard robotics?

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm

My friend has acquired a (small) wine yard to discover how much work it is tending and harvesting the grapes.

Now we are musing to enlist robotic help. The vine stocks are usually connected by a stiff wire, so some dangling machine might be feasible.

We are looking for references/inspirations for an agricultural robotic vine assistant. Any ideas?

Comment: While interesting, the question (as it is) is not a good fit for stackexchange. You'd need to do some research and come up with a more specific question.

Comment: Sorry for that... just getting started. Would be asking for "vertical movement of a dangling robot" be specific enough?

Comment: No. But asking for "why when I use motor X controlled with algorithm Y on a robot dangling from a wire, the robot doesn't move smoothly?" would make a specific enough question. The way the question is currently, is open-ended. The answers would be some vague idea of what may perhaps work. It doesn't produce solid answers that correctly solve a specific problem which can be reused in different applications. (Read more in the [faq](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask))

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1959/158) for example or [this one](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/2489/158) or [this one](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/2263/158) for a general idea of what is _specific enough_.

Comment: Thx for the hints, I'll try doing better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out this grape vine pruning robot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GaGO9LIDEA.